# Pass function result to tkinter GUI Text widget python3

Tags: python, tkinter

I am new to programming and I apologize if this is an obvious/trivial mistake. 
I am writing a GUI on tkinter using python 3.7.4 (with Thonny and/IDLE) on a computer running windows 10 64bit.

I am trying to write a GUI for the first time and I have the following problem:

I wrote a program to find any given document on the c-drive, open/read text, count the characters and then display the result. 
This works fine as long as I use the tkinter Frame widget but the frame widget does not allow for a scrollbar (i saw a few solutions for this that went right over my head) so i decided to use a text widget. there the line:

```
label2["text"] = a,"+", b, "+", c, "+", d, "=" , e
```

does not work for some reason and as I don't understand why it works in the first place I am not sure why it doesn't work now.

To make some tests I created a slightly easier to test code with the same problems:

```
import tkinter as tk
import random as rd

def fun9(d):
    a= rd.randint(1,10)
    b= rd.randint(1,10)
    c= rd.randint(1,10)
    #d= int(entry.get())
    e=a+b+c+d
    #label2["text"] = a,"+", b, "+", c, "+", d, "=" , e ### <-
    #label2.config(text = (a,"+", b, "+", c, "+", d, "=" , e))
    print(a,"+", b, "+", c, "+", d, "=" , e)
    return a,"+", b, "+", c, "+", d, "=" , e



root = tk.Tk() # root window?? -> opens window
root.geometry("%dx%d" % (800, 800))

# now write all functions
canvas = tk.Canvas(root) # create canvas for button
canvas.pack()

frame1 = tk.Frame(root, bg="#99ceff", bd=5)
frame1.place(relx=0.125, rely=0, relwidth=0.75, relheight=0.3)

label = tk.Label(frame1, font=20, text="here a, b, c and d are added: ")
label.place(relheight=1, relwidth=1)

frame2 = tk.Frame(root, bg="#99ceff", bd=5)
frame2.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.32, relwidth=0.75, relheight=0.1, anchor="n")

entry=tk.Entry(frame2, font=40, bd=5)# puts entry in frame instead of root
entry.place(relwidth=0.65, relheight=1)

button = tk.Button(root, text="Search and Display", bg="lightblue", font=40, command=lambda: fun9(int(entry.get()))) # creates button
button.place(relx=0.62, rely=0.32, relheight=0.1, relwidth=0.25) # places button in window

frame3 = tk.Frame(root, bg="#99ceff", bd=5)
frame3.place(relx=0.125, rely=0.45, relwidth=0.75, relheight=0.4)

#label2 = tk.Label(frame3, font=20)
#label2.place(relheight=1, relwidth=1)

label2 = tk.Text(frame3, font=20)
label2.pack()
label2.insert("1.0", fun9(int(entry.get())))
#label2.config(state="disabled")

root.mainloop()
```

the error message reads:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

so, as far as I see it, the input in the line

```
label2.insert("1.0", fun9(int(entry.get())))
```

doesn't pick up the entry value and I really don't understand why. I've tried to solve it for the last 3 days and I've read hours here and other places but I cannot find an answer (or at least not one I understand).

I appreciate any help and thank you very much

JD

ps: clicking the button will allow the programm to do its job in the command promt, just not in the gui frame (obviously ignoring the text widget)

Answer (score 0):

A core issue that is occurring is that fun9() is returning a tuple and then you attempting to cast that tuple as an int [line 68].

Comment: hey, thanks for the answer! is it possible you refer to line 36? (or line 47?) as far as i understand the code it has only 50 lines

Answer (score 0):

this is the answer i got from a friend, who is a software developer, so i can't take any credit for it! still maybe this will help someone else in the future, which is why i am posting it here:

```
import tkinter as tk
import random as rd

def fun9(result_textbox, d):
    a = rd.randint(1,10)
    b = rd.randint(1,10)
    c = rd.randint(1,10)
    e=a+b+c+d
    result = a,"+", b, "+", c, "+", d, "=" , e
    result_textbox.insert("1.0", result)
    print(result)
    return result



root = tk.Tk() 
root.geometry("%dx%d" % (800, 800))

# now write all functions
canvas = tk.Canvas(root) # create canvas for button
canvas.pack()

instruction_frame = tk.Frame(root, bg="#99ceff", bd=5)
instruction_frame.place(relx=0.125, rely=0, relwidth=0.75, relheight=0.3)

instruction_label = tk.Label(instruction_frame, font=20, text="here a, b, c and d are added: ")
instruction_label.place(relheight=1, relwidth=1)

entry_frame = tk.Frame(root, bg="#99ceff", bd=5)
entry_frame.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.32, relwidth=0.75, relheight=0.1, anchor="n")

entry=tk.Entry(entry_frame, font=40, bd=5)
entry.place(relwidth=0.65, relheight=1)

result_frame = tk.Frame(root, bg="#99ceff", bd=5)
result_frame.place(relx=0.125, rely=0.45, relwidth=0.75, relheight=0.4)

result_textbox = tk.Text(result_frame, font=20)

button = tk.Button(root, text="Search and Display", bg="lightblue", font=40, command=lambda: fun9(result_textbox, int(entry.get()))) # creates button
button.place(relx=0.62, rely=0.32, relheight=0.1, relwidth=0.25) # places button in window

result_textbox.pack()

root.mainloop()
```